# FeignClient call with consul service throws connection refused in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul, spring-cloud-feign

I have docker containers for consul and for my services. I have feign client interface trying to reach a service registered in consul. it works in the local testing (using localhost); however the same does not work in the container environment. 
the exception:

`web_1         | 2016-05-27 15:40:01.131  INFO 1 --- [gement-client-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client my-client initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=my-client,current list of Servers=[consul:9090],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {unknown=[Zone:unknown;    Instance count:1;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
web_1         | },Server stats: [[Server:consul:9090;   Zone:UNKNOWN;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
web_1         | ]}ServerList:ConsulServerList{serviceId='my-client', tag=null}
web_1         | 2016-05-27 15:40:02.088  INFO 1 --- [pool-5-thread-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: my-client.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
web_1         | 2016-05-27 15:40:02.525 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: getUser failed and no fallback available.] with root cause
web_1         |
web_1         | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
web_1         |     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
web_1         |     at feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:152) ~[feign-core-8.16.2.jar!/:8.16.2]
web_1         |     at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:74) ~[feign-core-8.16.2.jar!/:8.16.2]
web_1         |     at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]`

Comment: Are you running the container on local machine?

Comment: Assuming u are, you will have to run the container with -net=host option. Or else service will not be able to connect consul running on loclhost.